# Responsive Logo Positioning with Logo

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

Is there a better way to position a logo in the middle of the navigation? This is a wordpress build using the twitter bootstrap. I'm using absolute positioning but not sure what to do with the responsive aspect. Any input would be much appreciated. The url is: http://ndi.nowmgbeta.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way probably is to change the `<div class="brand-nmg">` to:

```
<div class="row-fluid brand-nmg text-center">
```

and remove the brand-nmg class from the link inside it.

Then use the following css:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
}
.brand-nmg {
    position: absolute;
}
```

(so remove the `left:` rule from .brand-nmg)

Comment: You're welcome :). Please accept my answer as the correct one (the green checkmark left of the answer)